# external javascript is not giving output

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p id="exp">Multiplication result</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="multiply()">Click me</button>
  <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function multiply() {
var x,y,z;
x=5;
y=10;
z=x*y;
var z=document.getElementById('exp').innerhtml;}
```

I am unable to find the problem why the script is not running.One more thing both file are in same directory.Thank you

Comment: innerHTML not innerhtml. Check your browser's console for error messages.

Comment: You've got typos _and_ you never output anything...

Comment: yes i made serious mistake i.e innerhtml instead of innerHTML and redeclaration of "z" variable.Thank you for pointing it out @AndyG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the last line, you are redeclaring "z" variable again with the value of the id="exp" element. If you want to assign the value of the operation to the HTML element you should do:

```
document.getElementById("exp").innerHTML = z;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,made silly mistakes in my first JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure What you are trying to do. But Javascript is working.
If you try to change Html, You cant change it like this.

```js
function multiply() {
  var x,y,z;
  x=5;
  y=10;
  z=x*y;
  console.log(z)
  var test = document.getElementById("exp").innerHTML; // check this
  console.log(test)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p id="exp">Multiplication result</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="multiply()">Click me</button>
  <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want push value of z to exp.U need set

`document.getElementById('exp').innerhtml = z;`

Hope this help